# Two different link web parts on one page problem

Tags: web-part, links-list

In one of my subsites, lets call it 'Our Workplace', I have two link lists called 'Employee Centre' and 'Manager Centre' respectively. They both contain a few folders with subfolders eventually linking to documents. I placed each of their web parts on a two column page layout (one on each column). They work fine but when I open a folder in one of them, say the management centre folders, all the sub folders and documents suddenly appear in the employee centre web part and disappear when I refresh or reload the page.. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Luke did you try on another PC ? This usually doesn't happen!

Comment: Yes but it was just another work PC, with the exact same specs. Same problem

Comment: Couldn't figure it out, so ended up just making links to another page and putting each list in their own page.

Comment: :( ... weird behaviour it was !